# R: how to create a single layer from multiple tiles that all together cover an area

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have four rasters (raster.1.mask, raster.2.mask, raster.3.mask, raster.4.mask) that all together cover a certain area of interest (they may overlap a little at the borders). What I want is to put those four rasters in a single one in order to perform some certain calculations.

I used:

```
mosaic(raster.1, raster.2, fun = mean, tolerance = 0.05)
```

and

```
raster::merge(raster.1.mask, raster.2.mask, tolerance = 0.05, overlap = FALSE)
```

but I am receiving the same error:

> "Error in compareRaster(x, extent = FALSE, rowcol = FALSE, orig =
>   TRUE,  :    different origin"

Comment: You need to provide [example data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and shape a reproducible example. Otherwise, it would not be easy to help you. Perhaps, there could be something wrong with `crs()` or more.

Comment: It is easy to make this reproducible by running `as.character(raster.1)` and so on for all rasters.